# Model differences of differences

Tags: r, model

We want to model how a continuous variable (A) vary (slope) in two different conditions (categorical variable B) accross another categorical variable (C) to answer the question. Does the metric used (C) to measure the change (A accross B) provide different outcomes?

I tried running a model with the interaction A ~ B * C and use the package "emmeans" in R to get the estimates and p-values that I want but it does not work.
Another option is to calculate first the differences of A in the two different conditions of B and use it as the response variable, but I think that is not the best approach, not sure why (do I have less power?, N is divided by 2).

Comment: I don't know about other but I usually find context is key. Could you give an example of what A,B and C are?

Comment: Thank you @LioElbammalf, sure. A is a metric describing a propertie of an interaction network metric (e.g. stability of the network). B is a factor with two levels (organic vs. conventional management), C is a categorical variable which levels refer to different algorithms that we used to measure the quantitative metric A. So, we want to know wether the differences found for A between networks sampled in organic vs. conventional farms vary depending on the algorithm (C levels) we used.

Comment: @Charly did you see my answer to your CV question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"`emmeans` does not work" is a pretty non-specific statement, as we have no idea what was attempted. But from the problem description, I surmise that it doesn't work for the same reason that a pair of pliers doesn't work when you need a screwdriver. In this case, a difference of differences is known as an interaction contrast. So what you can try is something like

```
mymodel = lm(A ~ B * C, data = mydata)  # is that the model you used?
(emm = emmeans(mymodel, ~ B * C))
emmip(emm, B ~ C)  # see an interaction plot of the predictions
(icon = contrast(emm, interaction = "consec"))
coef(icon)
```

The results for `icon` are the interaction contrasts, in this case differences of differences of means at consecutive levels. `coef(icon)` shows you exactly what the interaction contrasts are.

The **emmeans** package comes with an assortment of vignettes including a [FAQs vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/FAQs.html) and an [interactions vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/interactions.html), both of which give guidance on this sort of problem.